# Blur effect on the entire webpage

Tags: css

I want that the unregistered users on my website, see the entire website's pages with a blur effect.

How can I create this blur effect with css ?

Comment: blur effect as in fuzzy, blurry? Or as in greyed out. You need to be more specific.

Comment: Which browsers/versions do you need to support?

Comment: In my opinion this is crazy - if you're hiding content with css then anyone with a little knowledge of how css works could "unblur" your page and see all your content. Why not display a static blurry screenshot of the content (or something similar) instead?

Comment: I disagree that it's a bad idea, it could just be adding a stylistic touch. I started searching for a similar effect - in my case I'm blurring content under an overlay. An by blur, I mean as in the "blur" added to a .jpg graphic when compressing - do you mean the same thing xRobot?

Comment: Even if css blur was possible, using it to protect your online content will be easily circumvented. But even the motivation for this question may or may not be correct, the actual question of "how do I create a blur effect in css?" is a very valid one.

Comment: I want to achieve the same effect, but it has nothing to do with content protection. Just with design.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Full Page Blur in CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371209/full-page-blur-in-css)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's some results, if by blur you mean fuzziness:

This guy uses image shifting and opacity techniques in combo, I know your users are looking at a blurred website, but if there's no easy solution then perhaps taking a snapshot of your rego page and overlaying the image then it might do:

http://web.archive.org/web/20120211000759/http://simurai.com/post/716453142/css3-image-blur

If you wanted to attempt duplicating your rego page, given that it may be a) disabled and b) minimal, then perhaps you could even have a bash at using the above image technique and applying it to node sets, offsetting the copies with `CSS positioning` and `opacity` - idk if `zoom` might help you too there. Even if your page was minimal enough, this would obviously require Javascript to duplicate the nodes, unless your backend can do this node duplication. Just an idea, really. Here's a really awful, very quick example:

http://jsfiddle.net/9qnsz/2/

This SO posts outlines some of the limitations and difficulties with gaussian blur when not done with image, and has some interesting links:

[Gaussian Blur onHover Using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966949/gaussian-blur-onhover-using-jquery)

---

EDIT: As requested, the contents of the jsfiddle:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="overlay">
        <p>Please register etc etc...</p>
    </div>

    <form action="javascript:;" class="form0">
        <input type="text" value="Username" />
        <input type="text" value="Password" />
        <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
    <form action="javascript:;" class="form1">
        <input type="text" value="Username" />
        <input type="text" value="Password" />
        <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
    <form action="javascript:;" class="form2">
        <input type="text" value="Username" />
        <input type="text" value="Password" />
        <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
    <form action="javascript:;" class="form3">
        <input type="text" value="Username" />
        <input type="text" value="Password" />
        <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
    <form action="javascript:;" class="form4">
        <input type="text" value="Username" />
        <input type="text" value="Password" />
        <button>Submit</button>
    </form>

</div>​


.container {
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
}
    form {
        position:absolute;
        left:10px;
        top:10px;
    }
    form.form0 {
        left:11px;
        top:11px;
        opacity:0.1;
    }
    form.form1 {
        left:8px;
        top:8px;
        opacity:0.1;
        zoom:1.02;
    }
    form.form2 {
        left:11px;
        top:11px;
        opacity:0.1;
        zoom:1.01;
    }
    form.form3 {
        left:9px;
        top:9px;
        opacity:0.2;
    }
    form.form4 {
        left:11px;
        top:11px;
        opacity:0.1;
    }

    .overlay {
        width:250px;
        height:250px;
        margin-top:50px;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        border:1px solid #666;
    }
```

Comment: The simurai.com link 404's now.

Comment: Gooooo link-rot! But meh, the text description above the link pretty much explains what happened on that now dead link.

Comment: @Danjah Please post the relevant answer from the fiddle into the answer; otherwise when that link dies or is moved, your answer becomes useless.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker There you go! Just curious - is everyone required to add their jsfiddle input into their answers, posts and comments now?

Answer (score 8):

Try this...

```
body {
   filter:blur(3px);
}
```

You'll need to add -moz-, -webkit- prefixes (or use something like PrefixFree)

Answer (score 4):

**Edit (2015):** The `filter` css property is forming [tantalisingly complete coverage](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters). This lets you write rules like `body { filter: blur(10px); }`, which blurs the entire page.

---

From what I can tell, there's no cross-browser way of blurring an element, even in this "modern age" of html5, css3, etc...

There is a [blur filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532979%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for IE (and *only* IE). An [svg blur filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/applying_svg_effects_to_html_content) can also be [applied to an html element](http://www.peppertop.com/blog/?p=824) but from what I can tell, it only works in Firefox.

If you're happy for browser-specific hacks, go ahead, but if you need the effect to work on all browsers you're outta luck.

If you *just* want to blur text, you can use a clever text-shadow trick:

```
.blurry {
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0 0 3px black; /* set to colour you want */
}
```

There are also ways to blur images, either by overlaying transparent, shifted copies of the image, or by [processing the data with javascript](http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/actions/blur/).

Perhaps you can cobble together these techniques, and it will achieve what you want.

But the broad answer, regrettably, for the moment is: **there is no easy, holistic way to blur stuff in HTML**.

(I thought we were living in the future, man? What gives?!)

**Addendum:** Hope is in sight. At the time of writing, some webkit nightly ("bleeding edge") builds are implementing some of the new [css filter specification](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/css/filters/index.html). That demo doesn't work on any webkit browser I have installed, so it's still far from mainstream yet.

Answer (score -1):

You can add a fixed `div` set to 100% width and height to your `body`. That will fill the screen and you can put either a semi-transparent background on it or use CSS3 to create the effect you are looking for.

Comment: @aaaidan See this example: http://lab.simurai.com/iloveblur/ Basically set all text to have transparent color and a text-shadow.

Comment: That's a cool demo! Indeed it is a nice effect, and definitely equivalent to a blur. Unfortunately you can only use that technique on text, not to images, borders, fills, etc. (Notice that the heart in that example is a unicode heart! Sneaky!)

Comment: The I Love Blur demo was moved. Here's the new URL: http://simurai.com/lab/2010/06/10/i-love-blur

Answer (score -2):

Create a new `div` tag with `id="body_bag"` and put your rest of the site edits within that `div` and use following css to give the blur effect.

```
#body_bag {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #000;
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 50); /* required for opacity to work in IE */
}
```

Comment: How is this a blur? This is just going to make it look faded, right?