# Blur the whole page - Mouse Hover displays circle with inner non blurred

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've mapped out this cool idea for my personal web page.

I essentially just want to blur out the `<body>` and everything in it.

And **with mouse over -- a circle takes place of the mouse, with the inner non-blurred.**

Any simple JS / jQuery or CSS solutions?

*It would be cool to easily toggle a zoom for within the circle; but can do without.*

(Similar to this photo: http://medialoot.com/images/thumbs/640x440x1_Parallax_Wordpress_Theme_Preview31.jpg )

Comment: That is a cool effect.  Good luck!

Comment: Quick question: how long did you google for this / Did you google at all?

Comment: Hrm, perhaps not an exact duplicate after all (the circly thing). Can't unvote to close, though, sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a couple ideas:

This Fiddle does something like you're suggesting:
http://jsfiddle.net/jamygolden/CGFBT/2/light/

You would have to modify the hover effect so it only un-blurs the element beneath your mouse.

For images, you could make a sprite for every image that includes a blurred and focused version that flip-flop when you hover.

Answer (score 0):

There have been a couple of topics about this here before and the short answer is "No, not easily and even the hard way won't most likely achieve the effect you are after 100%". I think the mouse hover part will be the pain-in-the ass portion.

[Gaussian Blur onHover Using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966949/gaussian-blur-onhover-using-jquery)

[Blur effect on the entire webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267067/blur-effect-on-the-entire-webpage)
this one has some nice links