# Blur Images on Popup

Tags: javascript, css, popup

Is there any way on a pop up to not just blur the text, but images in the background? I have attached a visual.[image]

Comment: maybe this question could help you out? -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371209/full-page-blur-in-css

though it's pretty dated. there are css-filters which can be used for a blur effect in new (dev?) - builds of Chrome (prefixed with -webkit-)

Answer (score 5):

Maybe [blur.js](http://blurjs.com/) can help you out !!

Lookout for the [demo](http://blurjs.com/simpledemo.html).

Comment: woah, have a look at the markup, this base64-encoded background is crazy. But it's a nice find, +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are looking for. [CSS3 Lightbox](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/12/26/css3-lightbox/).

They have made a similar implementation of a popup and then blurring the background. Check it out. I am sure it will help with what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

*This is how stackoverflow does it.*

**HTML**

```
<div class="popup">

    <div class="blur-bg"></div>

    <div class="popup-win"><img src="foo.jpg"/></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
    .blur-bg{
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            z-index: 1000;
            opacity: 0.5;
            height: 2323px;
            left: 0px;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: black;
        }
    .popup-win{
            position: fixed;
            width: 400px;
            z-index: 1001;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            display: block;
            margin-top: -85px;
            margin-left: -215px;
            box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
            background-color: #fff;
            padding: 15px!important;
        }
```