# Create 'focus' circle with blurry background in HTML and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Today i found amazing filter button with 'circle black background' and i really liked it.
I want to integrate it in my website to study how to create it but i dont know how to start?
Maybe with create circle?

I have created floating button on my site (bottom right corner).You can find it [here](https://carhunt.bg/).When you scroll down to my website, the button will appear.So now i dont know how to create this circle with blurry background like example below?

[image]

My  floating button
[image]

Sorry for my bad English!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just created a playground for you here https://jsfiddle.net/rxnc3zb7/.
In general I added the following:

```
width:400px;
height:400px;
bottom:-150px;
right:-150px;
```

to the `.go-top:hover`. Set `width`, `height`, `bottom` and `right` values according to your needs. I've no tested it with the icon but I think you should hide it on hover (so `.go-top:hover i {opacity:0}`). But, if you want to center it you should set `.go-top` like this:

```
display:flex;
align-items:center;
justify-content:center;
```

In this way your icon will be aligned in any case.

**Blur effect**

For the blur effect I added a js code that simply add the class `blur-content` to the content container (in the example is `.content`) when the mouse is over on `.go-top` and remove it when mouse is out.

```
$('.go-top').hover(function(){
    $('.content').addClass("blur-content");

},function(){
    $('.content').removeClass("blur-content");
})
```

Additionally, I defined the `blur-content` class like this:

```
.blur-content{
  filter:blur(3px);
}
```

Comment: Thats a really good example but ca you make background blurry?

Comment: I just updated the playground to https://jsfiddle.net/rxnc3zb7/ adding the blur effect and the reply to explain it.

Comment: Hi! Sorry for asking again but is it possible to open orange circle when page is loaded?

Comment: Yes, you can add the class directly in the $(document).ready function and it will open it as soon as the document is ready (so the page is fully loaded).

Comment: which class? go-top is already added because it is implanted with hover , i want to display orange circle without hover the button

Comment: Take a look at this https://jsfiddle.net/84rthpw0/1/ I added a new class called on-hover and removed the maximize effect on :hover. Then I added the classes addition in the document ready

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea would be something like this. You can use CSS further to make it look more elegant. These applications generally have an Overlay in place which reacts to user button click or hover and display it.

You can use the below link to blur out your page contents or something similar
[Full Page Blur in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371209/full-page-blur-in-css)

```js
onBtnClick = ()=>{
document.getElementById("idBgOverlay").classList.toggle("overlayDisp");
}
```

```css
.fullBg{
  width:100%;
  height: 300px;
  background:orange;
}

.mybutton{
  border:none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color:#000;
  background:#fff;
  width:3rem;
  height:3rem;
  font-size:2rem;
  z-index:2;
  position:absolute;
}

.bgOverlay{
  background:#101010c7;
  position:absolute;
  height:13rem;
  width:13rem;
  border-radius:50%;
  top:-2rem;
  left:-2rem;
  display:none;
}

.overlayDisp{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="fullBg">
   <div id="idBgOverlay" class="bgOverlay"></div>
  <button class="mybutton" onclick="onBtnClick()"> + </button>
 
 <div>
```